# CartContextProvider error in next.js returns an empty page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

On Next.js, I'm setting up the cart functionality, but I encountered the following problem: I call CartContextProvider in _app.js, but it returns an empty page. I'll share the code and maybe someone can see what I'm doing wrong.
thanks

_app.js

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { CartContextProvider } from "@/components/CartContext";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <CartContextProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </CartContextProvider>
  );
}
```

CartContext.js

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const CartContext = createContext({});

export function CartContextProvider({ Children }) {
  const [cartProducts, setCartProducts] = useState([]);
  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ cartProducts, setCartProducts }}>
      {Children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Featured.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Center from "./Center";
import Button from "./Button";
import ButtonLink from "./ButtonLink";
import CartIcon from "./icons/CartIcon";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { CartContext } from "./CartContext";

const Bg = styled.div`
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 50px 0;
`;
const Title = styled.h1`
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 3rem;
`;
const Desc = styled.p`
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
`;
const ColumnsWrapper = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.2fr 0.8fr;
  gap: 40px;
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
`;
const Column = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;
const ButtonsWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
`;
export default function Featured({ product }) {
  const { setCartProducts } = useContext(CartContext);
  // console.log(setCartProducts);
  function addFeaturedToCart() {
    setCartProducts((prev) => [...prev, product._id]);
  }
  return (
    <Bg>
      <Center>
        <ColumnsWrapper>
          <Column>
            <div>
              <Title>{product.title}</Title>
              <Desc>{product.description}</Desc>
              <ButtonsWrapper>
                <ButtonLink
                  href={"/products/" + product._id}
                  outline={1}
                  white={1}
                  size="l"
                >
                  Read more
                </ButtonLink>
                <Button primary={1} onClick={addFeaturedToCart}>
                  <CartIcon />
                  Add to Cart
                </Button>
              </ButtonsWrapper>
            </div>
          </Column>
          <Column>
            <img src={product.images[0]} />
          </Column>
        </ColumnsWrapper>
      </Center>
    </Bg>
  );
}
```

Header.js

```
import Link from "next/link";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Center from "./Center";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { CartContext } from "./CartContext";

const StyledHeader = styled.header`
  background-color: #222;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
`;
const Logo = styled(Link)`
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
`;
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 0;
`;
const StyledNav = styled.nav`
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
`;
const NavLink = styled(Link)`
  color: #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
`;
export default function Header() {
  const { cartProducts } = useContext(CartContext);
  return (
    <StyledHeader>
      <Center>
        <Wrapper>
          <Logo href={"/"}>Ecommerce</Logo>
          <StyledNav>
            <NavLink href={"/"}>Home</NavLink>
            <NavLink href={"/product"}>All products</NavLink>
            <NavLink href={"/categories"}>Categories</NavLink>
            <NavLink href={"/account"}>Account</NavLink>
            <NavLink href={"/cart"}>Cart({cartProducts.length})</NavLink>
          </StyledNav>
        </Wrapper>
      </Center>
    </StyledHeader>
  );
}
```

Hello friends.

On Next.js, I'm setting up the cart functionality, but I encountered the following problem: I call CartContextProvider in _app.js, but it returns an empty page. I'll share the code and maybe someone can see what I'm doing wrong.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're destructuring props in your CartContextProvider.
In the CartContextProvider component, you've used { Children } (with a capital C), but React uses { children } (with a lowercase c) by convention to denote the children props. Due to this, the Children prop is undefined and nothing is being rendered inside the CartContext.Provider.

change it to:

```
export function CartContextProvider({ children }) {
```

and:

```
return (
<CartContext.Provider value={{ cartProducts, setCartProducts }}>
  {children}
</CartContext.Provider>
```

);